# TypeError when I deploy my project with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an error when I triy to open my web site in production mode, when I deploy my website I have this error

```
react-dom.production.min.js:216 TypeError: Cannot read property 'logged' of null
at Q (AppRouter.jsx:24)
at al (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
at Hi (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
at Ou (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at Cu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at xu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at vu (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
at fu (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
at Gu (react-dom.production.min.js:285)
at react-dom.production.min.js:289

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'logged' of null
at Q (AppRouter.jsx:24)
at al (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
at Hi (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
at Ou (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at Cu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at xu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at vu (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
at fu (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
at Gu (react-dom.production.min.js:285)
at react-dom.production.min.js:289
```

These are some components

**Types:**

```
    export const types = {

    login: '[auth] login',
    logout: '[auth] logout'

}
```

**AuthReducer:**

```
    import { types } from "../types/types";

export const AuthReducer = ( state={}, action ) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case types.login :
            return {
                ...action.payload,
                logged: true
            }
        
        case types.logout:
            return {
                logged: false
            }
            
    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Context**

```
    import { createContext } from 'react'

export const AuthContext = createContext();

**App.jsx:**

    import { Fragment, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./auth/authContext";
import { AuthReducer } from "./auth/authReducer";
import { AppRouter } from "./routers/AppRouter";


function App() {

  const init = () => {
    return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'user' ) )
  }

  const [user, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, {}, init)

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
  }, [user])

  return (
    <Fragment>
      
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{
        user,
        dispatch
      }}>
        <AppRouter/>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
            
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**DashBoardRoutes**

```
    export const DashBoardRouter = () => {
    return(
        <>
            <NavBar/>
            
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ HomePage } />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={ AboutPage } />
                <Route exact path="/marvel" component={ MarvelPage } />
                <Route exact path="/dc" component={ DcPage } />
                <Route exact path="/heroe/:heroeId" component={ HeroPage } />
                <Route exact path="/search" component={ SearchPage } />
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
            
        </>
    )
}
```

The problem occurs when I deploy my project in some host like netlify, in development mode all the code work well.
As you can see I only use reactjs, react-router-dom, context, and reducer, I have seen in some quetions of gitHub issues that maybe the problem is the context but I don´t know how to resolve this issue..

Comment: do you use lazy loading in you application ?

Comment: Remove localStorage data or try in the incognito mode. In my opinion, It will be the same issue because when you read localStorage and the data doesn't exist it returns null and null is also proper JSON